# Como verificar valor nulo em linhas de uma coluna de um dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Eu estou querendo substituir os valores nulos pelo valor do ano.

Dado o seguinte dataframe :

```
year value
2000  1
NaN   2
NaN   3     
NaN   4
NaN   5
NaN   6  
2001  1
NaN   2
NaN   3     
NaN   4
NaN   5
NaN   6  
...
2020  1
NaN   2
NaN   3     
NaN   4
NaN   5
NaN   6
```

Os valores nulos entre os anos, por exemplo de 2000 e 2001 eu gostaria de substituir por 2000 até chegar em 2001 e assim por diante. Deveria ficar algo assim :

```
year value
2000   1
2000   2
2000   3     
2000   4
2000   5
2000   6
2001   1
2001   2
2001   3     
2001   4
2001   5
2001   6  
...
2020   1
2020   2
2020   3     
2020   4
2020   5
2020   6
```

Eu tentei fazer assim:

```
tam = df["year"].size
val = df.iloc[0,0]
for i in range(tam):
    if df.iloc[i,0]==None:
        df.iloc[i,0]=val
    else:
        val = df.iloc[i,0]
```

Mas o dataframe continua o mesmo. Ao que parece a condição if `df.iloc[i,0]==None` não funciona.
Nesse sentido como verificar se um elemento de uma coluna é nulo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o `fillna()` com o método de preenchimento 'forward fill'

```
df['year'].fillna(method = 'ffill', inplace = True)
```

Entrada:

```
    year    value
0   2000     1
1   NaN      2
2   NaN      3
3   NaN      4
4   NaN      5
5   NaN      6
6   NaN      7
7   2001     8
8   NaN      9
9   NaN      10
10  NaN      11
11  NaN      12
12  NaN      13
13  2020     14
```

Saída:

```
    year    value
0   2000    1
1   2000    2
2   2000    3
3   2000    4
4   2000    5
5   2000    6
6   2000    7
7   2001    8
8   2001    9
9   2001    10
10  2001    11
11  2001    12
12  2001    13
13  2020    14
```

Comment: Perfeito, não conhecia esse comando. Obrigado.

Comment: Fala Beto, bom dia! Por nada! Abraço!!